# Como hacer sumas y restas de una columna desde php a mysql

Tags: mysqli, select, sum

Bueno mi pregunta es como puedo hacer sumas y restas de columnas desde un boton y que se guarde en otra columna

Index.php

```
<?php   session_start();    if (@!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location:index.php");   }elseif ($_SESSION['rol']==1) {
    header("Location:admin.php");   }   ?>
```

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "academ"); $sql =
"SELECT * FROM reporte";   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
SELECT (horaemision-horaintervencion)as tiempoefectivo from reporte
SELECT (horaintervencion-horaemision)as tiempomuerto from reporte ?>

```
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
   </fieldset> </
```

form>

No me guarda nada en la otra columna a la hora de hacer el reporte

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es arreglar un poco tu código, no se entiende mucho.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.